# Extracting a part of PDF page using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a pdf page with 4 vector images in it.
I need to split this page into 4 pdf pages using itextSharp. 
Can this be done?

I am not posting the code which I have tried till now as it will cause confusion. Please bear with me.

Regards

Comment: You want to extract images from your pdf and after put every in some separate page?

Comment: http://www.winnovative-software.com/PdfImgExtractor.aspx